# OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"orderer1\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

i have a trouble regarding launching the container with the address (orderer1.IdentityPreservationSystem.com). i have 2 orderer services both are generating same errors . Environment settings could be seen as follows

> orderer1.IdentityPreservationSystem.com:
>       container_name: orderer1.IdentityPreservationSystem.com
>       image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.2.1
>       environment:
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=Orderer1MSP
>         - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer1/msp
>       working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
>       command: orderer1
>       ports:
>         - 7049:7049
>       volumes:
>           - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
>           # - ./channel-artifacts:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
>           - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/IdentityPreservationSystem.com/orderers/orderer1.IdentityPreservationSystem.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer1/msp

Command used

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up orderer1.IdentityPreservationSystem.com
```

Complete Output :

> Starting orderer1.IdentityPreservationSystem.com ... error
>
> ERROR: for orderer1.IdentityPreservationSystem.com  Cannot start
>   service orderer1.IdentityPreservationSystem.com: OCI runtime create
>   failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused
>   "exec: \"orderer1\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
>
> ERROR: for orderer1.IdentityPreservationSystem.com  Cannot start
>   service orderer1.IdentityPreservationSystem.com: OCI runtime create
>   failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused
>   "exec: \"orderer1\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
>   ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: What is with the name of your ordering service at the end of the docker-compose up command. The system is parsing that as a command and trying to run it

Comment: orderer1.IdentityPreservationSystem.com

Comment: Can you share your docker-compose-dev.yml file

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem today. It turned out my server was after running out of memory (RAM). There was few containers running.

Comment: i cleared up everything . restarting of docker . removing container , removing inactive containers , restarting the machine ......Problem persists.

Comment: Sorry when I said memory I meant RAM memory and not disk space.